# Curl CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER not working as expected?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to load a page with Curl. The page loads properly, just like I expected. But the problem is Curl prints the whole content out instead of saving it into a variable as I want to.

The code looks like this:

```
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Except for the initializations, this is the whole content of the php file. It can't get much simpler than this but yet it prints out the content and does not save it into the variable $result.

I tried:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

also I tried a bunch of other addresses, same result.
Did I miss something?

Maybe I have to set another Curl option or I have to change some settings of my test server?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked as it should.  As a dirty workaround, you could capture the output using output buffering (ob_start and the like).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I guess It could be a server side problem, I'm using the most simple and portable webserver I could find (server2go) and I already had to make some changes so the database would be preserved and Curl would be enabled.

I'll keep the question open for a while longer in case someone had the same problem and knows the solution. Else I'll try your suggestion and capture the output before it is displayed.

Comment: You could try out xampp, they also have a portable edition.  Perhaps that might function as expected.

Comment: Again, thank you for your quick answer. I don't know where I made a mistake (maybe even a syntactical mistake), but after I deleted the code and wrote the exact same thing again except for the html code surrounding it (<html>, <head> and <body> tags and a few script includes), it works.

The code works, it seems I was just sloppy and made a mistake somewhere in the code :s

Comment: :-) Happens to the best of us.  Perhaps close this question then since it isn't a question any more :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I was *returning* rather than *echoing* the return data. When I echoed the return value all was well.

EDIT: It was for an AJAX command using jQuery.

Comment: Were you [using `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` as well](http://es1.php.net/curl_setopt#87341)?

Comment: No I wasn’t using that curl option.